# Gitlab OpenID Connect integration fails with certificate verify failed

Tags: gitlab-omnibus

I'm trying to integrate Gitlab (deployed from docker image `gitlab/gitlab-ce`) with our internal OpenID provider and getting error 500 and the following message in logs when trying to authenticate

```
OpenIDConnect::Discovery::DiscoveryFailed (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)):
lib/gitlab/middleware/rails_queue_duration.rb:27:in `call'
lib/gitlab/metrics/rack_middleware.rb:17:in `block in call'
lib/gitlab/metrics/transaction.rb:57:in `run'
lib/gitlab/metrics/rack_middleware.rb:17:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/multipart.rb:103:in `call'
lib/gitlab/request_profiler/middleware.rb:16:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:20:in `call'
lib/gitlab/etag_caching/middleware.rb:13:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/correlation_id.rb:16:in `block in call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/correlation_id.rb:15:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only/controller.rb:40:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only.rb:18:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/basic_health_check.rb:25:in `call'
lib/gitlab/request_context.rb:26:in `call'
lib/gitlab/metrics/requests_rack_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/release_env.rb:12:in `call'
```

Our OpenID provider uses TLS certs signed by internal CA. I installed the CA certs using standard Debian `update-ca-certificates` in the Gitlab container and also put them in `/etc/gitlab/trusted-certs` and reconfigured/restarted everything, without success.

I have `gitlab.rb` set up for OIDC according to [this doku](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/auth/oidc.html).

Answer (score 1):

Updated my config in line with a different example

```
    gitlab_rails['omniauth_providers'] = [
      {
        'name' => 'oauth2_generic',
        'label' => 'IDP',
        'app_id' => 'my-app-id',
        'app_secret' => 'xxx',
        'args' => {
          client_options: {
            'site' => 'https://idp.example.com/auth/realms/example.com/protocol/openid-connect/',
            'authorize_url' => 'auth',
            'user_info_url' => 'userinfo',
            'token_url' => 'token'
          },
          user_response_structure: {
            id_path: 'preferred_username',
            attributes: { nickname: 'preferred_username' }
          },
          name: 'oauth2_generic',
          strategy_class: 'OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2Generic'
        },
      }
    ]
```

and it works!

But no idea why any of the changes should be related to certificate validation :(

Comment: Hi, could you share what are the configuration values set in your OpenID provider? particularly the "AllowedScopes" values for your gitlab. I am getting invalid request from my OpenID provider as the "AllowedScopes" in is set to "email openid profile" and the scope attribute is not in the GET request.

Comment: I have added the scopes to the authorize_params field and it has redirected to my OpenID provider's login page successfully. However, after logging in, I am getting a 401 Unauthorized when it redirects back to gitlab. Any ideas on what could be the error throwing the 401 Unauthorized response. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, can't check, it was just a PoC, and was destroyed some time ago.